# How to port android application developed for 1.6 to 2.x to tablet 3.0?

Tags: android

How to port android application developed for 1.6 to 2.x to tablet 3.0?

I have made the changes in manifest file about the targetSDK but still the application doesn't utilizes the components or the theme of tablet. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at a few pages in the doc:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html - particularly the section "Select a theme based on platform version"

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html - see "Adding the action bar"

Are you adding a theme to your app that doesn't use one of the Holo themes?

(And closely related to your question: you also want to look at the [compatibility library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html), for Honeycomb features in 2.X and 1.6 applications)